# Nginx webp image не отображается

Tags: python, веб-программирование, nginx, веб-сервер, webp

Столкнулся с проблемой связанной с nginx. В моём проекте используется nginx (1.17.1) c pagespeed модулем. При обработке папки /static/ работает всё отлично, но принципивльно не отображаются изображения .webp Пример конфигурации

```
location /static/ {
        #webo
        # if ($http_accept ~* "webp")    { set $webp_accept "true"; }
        # if (-f $request_filename.webp) { set $webp_local  "true"; }

        # # если WebP есть, то передать Vary
        # if ($webp_local = "true") {
        #     add_header Vary Accept;
        # }

        # # если клиент поддерживает WebP, то передать файл
        # if ($webp_accept = "true") {
        #     rewrite (.*) $1.webp break;
        # }
        if ($http_accept ~* "webp") { set $webp T; }



        # optimization
        etag on;
        #gzip on;
        charset utf-8;
        expires max;
        # sendfile on;
        sendfile off;
        # autoindex on;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        # root /home/project/src/;
        alias /home/project/src/static/;
    }
```

При попытке обратится к этому изображению(https:site//static/image/usa.wepb) получаю ошибку 404. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Никогда, и ни при каких обстоятельствах не вкладывайте `if`  в `location`. Это, если и будет работать, то с разного рода "странностями".

Comment: хорошо, даже если просто поставить $webp T; файл просто отдаёт 404

Comment: Почему собственно "играете" с `$http_accept`? - если вы действительно используете PageSpeed, он всё делает за вас и ничего особенного чтобы "работали" WebP делать не нужно с ним.

Comment: мне тоже так казалось, но оно webp просто не отображает. На все изображения 404

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется есть проблема в понимании работы PageSpeed.

Скажем, у вас есть `http://example.com/foo.jpg`. Это не значит что у вас будет работать ссылка вида `http://example.com/foo.webp`. Это значит что *страница* на которой есть ссылка `http://example.com/foo.jpg` будет переписана другим HTML и ссылка на изображение будет другой (например на `foo.jpg.pagespeed.ic.e9YEVHVh-S.webp`) (в зависимости от браузера и после того как изображение будет переведено в другой формат, в фоне).

Просто откройте страницу (именно страницу, а не изображение), чтобы произошла оптимизация используемых на ней ресурсов. Так оно работает.